# Vlookup with Hyperlink - VBA

Tags: vba, hyperlink, vlookup

I'm currently seaching to find a way to copy and paste hyperlink link from another sheet.

The way the program supposed to be working is that you choose from a list a item category and then all the following columns are automatically filled with Vlookup check-up on the ''Category'' Sheet

The problem :
Need to keep the hyperlink when copy and past the information, I'm still new in the code and currently have no idea how to make it worked.

I really want to keep the VBA, because the code is hide and people won't be able to mess with it and can write on top off the cell for special case.

```
Sub Update()
 Dim calData As String
 Dim add As String
 Dim i, LastRow
 LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 3 To LastRow
 If Cells(i, "G").Value <> "" Then
    Range("Q" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 4, False)
    Range("R" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 6, False)
    'Set calData = Worksheets("Calendar").Range("R" & i)
    'add = "G:\Engineering\Engineering trainees (HUG)\Etalonnage\Procédures calibration\" & Data
        'With Worksheets("Calendar")
        '.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=.Range("R" & i), _
        'Address:=add, _
        'TextToDisplay:=Data
        'End With
    Range("S" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 7, False)
    Range("T" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 8, False)
 End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close. Try below code.
Note as a practice, try not to use "add" as a variable name. It messes the IntelliSense, i changed to `addr`.
Wouldn't the Q,R,S,T columns better off with Formula instead of fixed value? Unless you have an Event code to call this Sub when cells in column G are changed.

```
Sub Update()
    Dim calData As String
    Dim addr As String
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, "G").Value <> "" Then
            Range("Q" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 4, False)
            Range("R" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 6, False)

            calData = Worksheets("Calendar").Range("R" & i).Value ' Or .Text, depends on data
            addr = "G:\Engineering\Engineering trainees (HUG)\Etalonnage\Procédures calibration\" & calData
            With Worksheets("Calendar")
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("R" & i), Address:=addr, TextToDisplay:=calData
            End With

            Range("S" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 7, False)
            Range("T" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, "G"), Sheets("Category").Range("A2:H60"), 8, False)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```